# Define "Indirect subclass" in Android

Tags: android, class

Looking at various [pages in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html), some of them list "Known Indirect Subclasses". What does this mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an interface, it's a list of classes that implement the interface.

For a class, it's a list of classes that derive from the class, but indirectly (ie., the class in the list is derived from some class that itself derives from the class being documented directly or indirectly).

So the `android.view.ViewGroup` derives directly from `android.view.View` and indirectly from `java.lang.Object`:

```
java.lang.Object
    android.view.View
        android.view.ViewGroup
```

Since interfaces can only be implemented, not directly derived from, a class that implements an interface is always considered to be 'indirectly derived' from the interface.